# Can we stylize the number in an ordered list without changing the entire li?

Tags: css

Is it possible with **CSS** to change the style of the number in an ­`<ol>` without changing the entire text in the `<li>` without adding extra markup around the li content?

Comment: @Andy: Please, **DO NOT** link to w3schools for any reason. It is a [horribly bad site](http://w3fools.com) which does **not** need more backlinks increasing their pagerank.

Comment: @Andy: Here are some better ones: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/list-style-type, http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-type, http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/list-style-type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the original `<ol>` style, then use `:before` selector with counters to add whatever style you want. Like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pVG75/1/):

```
ol {
    counter-reset: i 0;
}
ol li:before {
    content: counter(i);    
    counter-increment: i;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    color: red;
}
```

If you wish, you can even override some styles for particular elements of the list with [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anth-child) selector ([JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pVG75/3/)):

```
ol li:nth-child(3):before {
    color: violet;
}
```

... as cascading rules are still applied here. Note, though, that `nth-child` is not supported by IE8.

Comment: The sibling selector IS supported in IE8 though, so you can achieve the same chaining `+`'s like so: http://jsfiddle.net/pVG75/4/

Comment: @Andy what happens if the list has 5 or more items in it?  If you need old IE support to style exactly the 3rd one, you need this selector:  `ol li:first-child + li + li` instead of `ol li + li + li`

Comment: Maybe you can help me on a fallow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976914/can-we-retreive-the-default-counter-value-of-an-li

Comment: @Andy and when the list has 100 items on it?  How about 200?  Will you continue adding selectors?

Comment: @Andy my point is, you're adding multiple selectors when only 1 is necessary.

Comment: @cimmanon I wasn't contesting that `:nth-child` is superior, I'm a huge fan of it, but if OP wants to support IE8 he can't use that.

Comment: Can you do this with letters rather than numbers?