# Can we retrieve the default counter value of an li?

Tags: css

Can we retrieve in **CSS** the default counter value of an li?
**For example:**
If I have 6 `<li>`, separated in 2 `<ol>`, but I want the `<li>` to be listed from 1 to 6, not 1 to 3 twice. I used `value="4"` on the first `<li>` of the second `<ol>`, so it worked, but now since I'm using

```
ol {
  counter-reset: i 0;
}

ol li:before {
    content: counter(i);    
    counter-increment: i;
    font-weight: bold;
}​
```

The `content: counter(i);` to not take in count the `value="4"` on the first `<li>` of the second `<ol>`.

Is there something I can do about this?

View on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MC8aP/)

Comment: This may be possible in the future with `li[data-value] { counter-reset: i attr(data-value number); }`, but I don't see any way to do it now.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this suit your needs? [View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hg4yg/)

### HTML

```
<ol>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ol>
<ol>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ol>
```

### CSS

```
ol:first-of-type {
  counter-reset: i 0;
}

ol li:before {
  content: counter(i);    
  counter-increment: i;
  font-weight: bold;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out I just need to do the `counter-reset` on the parent instead of all `<ol>`
 [View example](http://jsfiddle.net/MC8aP/1/) for details.